# Network Interface does not come up automatically

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, ethernet, ifconfig

I have a couple of Jetson TK1s and Jetson TX1s running Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux4Tegra).  I need to be able to switch between two network configurations - an "office" one where I'm in the office and can access the company network (DHCP), and a "field" one where the the network interface is static.  To do this I have two network interfaces files:

/etc/network/interfaces_office:

```
auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

#allow-hotplug eth0
#   iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

/etc/network/interfaces_field:

```
auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.20.3.137
    netmask 255.0.0.0
```

My **/etc/network/interfaces** file is then just a symlink that I can easily change to point to which file I'd like to use.  This setup works fantastic on the TK1s that I have.

On my TX1 though, whenever I do this, eth0 doesn't come up automatically on startup.  I've disabled network manager (by creating a /etc/init/network-manager.override file that contains "manual") to make sure it's not interfering somehow.

When I connected to the serial port with an FTDI cable to monitor the start up the message **RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable** is displayed repeatedly until I manually start eth0 using **sudo ifup eth0** 
Is there a reason eth0 won't come up automatically?

I would really like to use the `allow-hotplug` option that's commented out above instead of just `auto` so that booting the Jetson isn't delayed if the network cable isn't in. I'm also not sure if this is  Jetson issue or an Ubuntu issue so this is also posted [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/934533/network-interface-does-not-come-up-automatically/#4873456).